# How to read $( x^{2x^{-1/5}})^{-1}=\frac{1}{25}$

Tags: exponentiation

I saw the following problem

$$\left( x^{2x^{-\frac{1}{5}}} \right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{25}$$

and I was curious whether I should read it as

$$\left( (x^{2x})^{(-\frac{1}{5})} \right)^{-1}$$

or
$$\left( x^{(2x^{\frac{1}{5}})} \right)^{-1}$$

to clarify, am I to raise 2x to the -1/5 power first, or raise $x^{2x}$ to the -1/5 power?

Comment: usually $a^{b^c}$ is read as $a^{(b^c)}$; cf. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties)

Comment: $2a^b$ means $2\cdot(a^b)$, not $(2a)^b$.

Comment: $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$ usually (for instance, when you are awake).

Comment: I would say it is $\left( x^{2\left(x^{-\frac{1}{5}}\right)} \right)^{-1}$

Comment: @ECL I agree with you. Simplifying it results in $x^x = 5^5$

Comment: thanks that helps a lot, some of the confusion on my part might have been the typeface used in the original problem....

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is take the reciprocal of both sides:
$x^{2x^{-1/5}}= 25$.  From there, because you have "$x$" both as the base and in the exponent I expect you will need the "W function".

Comment: Please check your formatting again.

Comment: Since $25=5^2,$ we can find the real valued solution without W.